# Is it possible to hide icons on the dock of apps that are running on other spaces?

Tags: macos, dock, osx-spaces, workspace

I was wondering if it is possible to hide icons on the dock of apps that are running on other spaces. Also I would like the app-switcher to show only the apps that are working on the current desktop I'm using.
In short: I would like the space I'm using to be somehow isolated from the other spaces.

Comment: It's not considered polite to cross-post the same question across different SE sites - especially when the best answer was "Neither of the things you are asking for are possible, at least not without a deep system-level hack."

Comment: @Tutsujin Sorry but I posted it there and then I said "people who use superuser may be more experienced, so why not give it a try"